# ImageResizer - Map URLs with ImageHandlerSyntax plugin

Tags: imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I'm trying to use Image resizer with **Diskcache** pluing to serve 100000+ images to a ecommerce website. The problem is, I need to stick in to the current URL pattern in the ecommerce site.

I tried URL rewrites to achieve that, but it doesn't work.

I saw that I can use **ImageHandlerSyntax** plugin to map existing URL patterns to work with **Diskcache**. But the documentation is very limited and I cannot get a clear Idea on how to configure it.

Can someone kindly explain how to configure ImageHandlerSyntax plugin to map URL patterns?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite event handler - you can modify the url and query any way you want there.